# How do I define a shortcut key in Eclipse to generate ALL javadoc for my project

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I generate javadoc for my project often. Doing this in Eclipse requires 6 mouse clicks (Project/Generate Javadoc/Open Project Tree/Unselect Src box/Select Src box/Finish).

Is there a shortcut key that I'm missing? Or a plug-in to make this generation easier?

Comment: Take a look at this link.
It's an Eclipse plug-in absolutely for interaction with Java-docs. http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Reading the doc it seems to be more about automatically adding javadoc to your code rather than making generating the HTML easier. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the third/last page of the ***Javadoc Generation* wizard/dialog** there is the checkbox ***Save the settings of this Javadoc export as an Ant Script*** for that.

The Ant script generated in this way can be launched via right-click *Run As > Ant Build*. If the Ant script was executed once, you can click on the *Run Last Tool* icon in the main toolbar to run it again. In addition, in *Window > Preferences: General > Keys* you can specify a shortcut for *Run Last Launched External Tool* command.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. thanks.